# WordPress Timing Out

Tags: php, wordpress, centos

Currently I am receiving the following error whenever I attempt to bulk update posts. This is even happening with just 5 posts at once and with little or no ouside server requests. Any ideas on how to resolve?

"The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems."

Server: Digital Ocean

2GB Ram 40GB SSD Disk CentOS 7 x64

PHP 5.4.16 / Memory Limit is 128M.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your `php.ini` file, it is pre-defined. Open `php.ini` file and change the following lines

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 257M
```

**change the above numbers based on your need.**

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've adjusted my .ini file but still running into the same issue. I've also set my timeout to 300 just in case.

Comment: you may need to restart your server for reflect tha changes

Comment: Rebooted the server and also set the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT to 256M in the wp-config file, but unfortunately its still timing out.

Comment: actually in your question, it shows only memory out. Is there any time out occur?? if so give ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); in your php page. time should be given in milli seconds

Comment: No, I misstated. The only error I'm receiving is the one above. I'm just trying anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Just received the same error again when simply attempting to navigate to the WP Setting menu.